# "A valid provisioning profile for this executable could not be found"

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

One of our former colleagues created an iPad app for a client. This app has recently stopped working out of the blue. The app simply opens and then closes immediately again.

I have attached one of the ipads to a Macbook and used the Organizer in XCode to check the logs. I see the following line being printed right before the app closes:
"A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."

The provisioning profile has indeed been renewed recently, so I upload the new profile through iTunes onto the iPad. I check via Settings > Profiles and I see my distribution file right there, so I know it's installed correctly.

Stil, the app won't open up at all and continues to write "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."

How can I discover what provisioning profile that app is looking for?

And if I should reinstall the app on the iPad, can somehow give a link on how to do that with XCode?

Comment: did u updated the code signing identity with the new provisioning profile in your project settings?

Comment: and also, have the device UUID registered with the profile .

Comment: try using TestFlightApp  :)

Answer (score 2):

There is few things that can check first

1. Check that your bundle ID corresponds to the bundle ID defined in your new provisioning profile.
2. Check the code signing in build settings of your app target by selecting your app in the left panel of xcode, then select build settings and check code signing identity. Make sure you have your new provisioning profile selected there.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not update your product provisioning certificate after your **ios dev Account** renew.

- login with your Apple id that created your `product provisioning certificate`
- Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles--> select your provisioning select that you are trying to use like bellow image:

[image]

- select your valide distribution cer for this production cer that you are using previously.

[image]

- after this press generate button and download this in to your system. Double click on this. and use this hope that working now.

**NOTE:** check that your developer/distribution cer not invalide that active in to your keychain with private key. Check you are selected certificate is working and active Mode.

**MORE:**

If you are using **xCode5** then there is certificate profile not displying as like we see in organization tab like xCode4.x

for check your certificate is update you need to follow this bellow steps in xCode5

[image: *]

add you apple id that you are using.

[image]

- after adding your apple id there is right side show Details Button press there and press refresh icon that refresh your all certificate then you can setting provisional prifile from Project->target->build setting->code sign.

Answer (score 1):

Before connecting the device to the Xcode for installing the app, you have to add that device's UDID to the developer(not distribution) provisioning profile of the application.

And then download and open that profile in organizer window and then update the code signing identity in the build settings on both project and settings.

Now connect the iPad and run the app. Check whether you had missed any of the above.